# credhub login does not work after deploying CF on virtualbox using Bosh

Tags: cf-bosh

I have installed CF on virtualbox using BOSH. Now I would like to use CF CLI and install an application on CF. For that, I am following instructions here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/master/deployment-guide.md

It suggests to run "credhub login" and get the CF credentials to log in to CF. However, credhub login does not work. It doesn't identify the credhub command. My understanding is that credhub gets installed along with CF during deployment process which doesn't seem to be the case.

I am wondering how do i fetch the admin password for Cloud Foundry that I just installed on a virtualbox using bosh as credhub doesn't seem to work. 
I also don't see a password for CF in credhub.yml in bosh-deployment folder.
I am not sure how this works. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The credhub CLI needs installing before you can use its commands: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/credhub-cli

Comment: Does this need to be installed before or after deploying cf on virtualbox using bosh ? I installed it after the fact and I don't understand where /bosh-lite/cf/cf_admin_password path is after I run credhub find -n cf_admin_password as suggested by the instructions